# Insert vector<string> on N position into vector<vector<double>>

Tags: c++, 2d-vector

So my problem is I have this file which I have to read and search info on it to then return it/print it, so I did and got all my file's info into a `vector<string>`.
So now I am looking to extract certain data from the `vector<string>` into my `vector<vector<double>>` from stringVector[N], to do this I am trying the following:

```
vector<vector<double>>twoDdoublevector;
vector<string>stringvector;

//cycle that goes on for a few iterations
{
    std::vector<double>temp;
    temp.push_back(stod(stringvector[newcount++]));
    temp.push_back(stod(stringvector[newcount++]));
    temp.push_back(stod(stringvector[newcount++]));
    twoDdoublevector.push_back(temp);
}
```

I don't know what exactly is going wrong, since it will just continue running, without finishing or showing anything.

Comment: You will have to show the loop and its conditions to get any helpful answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and you were right, this works perfectly fine, I had a mistake on my loop...